# How to pass a symbol stored in table to a stored procedure condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have 2 tables like below:

**Table 1**:

```
call c1 c2 
---- -- -- 
c001  a  10
c001  a  11
c001  b  13
c001  b  25
```

**Table 2**:

```
call description symbol limit
---- ----------- ------ -----
c001  Gain         >      10
c002  loss         <      1
c003  safe         =      0
```

I am trying to write a stored procedure where we can pass the symbol and limit to get the results.

```
SELECT 
    t1.call, t1.c1, (t1.C2 - t2.C2)     
    CASE ( MOD(t1.c2-t2.c2) t3.symbol (select t3.limit from table2 t3), 'FAIL', 'PASS') STATUS
FROM 
    table1 t1, table1 t2
WHERE 
    t1.C1 = t2.C1 AND t3.call = t1.call
```

and the result looks like this:

```
call c1 c2 STATUS
---- -- -- ------
C001 a  1  FAIL
C001 b  12 PASS
```

Please assist.

Comment: The only way you are likely to be able to achieve this is by using dynamic SQL.  Does your server instance permit this?

Comment: yes it will. But I am not sure how to get this done.

Comment: Is this an old, existing production system somewhere, or are you developing something new? (Or is this just for practice?) It is a brain-dead way to store business logic; if you have to put up with something created by others fifteen years ago that's one thing, but if it's a new system, DO SOMETHING ELSE. And if it's for practice only, practice something else; practicing doing something dumb is the worst kind of practice you can have.

Comment: This is for a new system. Looks like it is doable but still not. wanted to give it a try.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

You could use another level of case expression to decide which symbol to use:

```
select t1a.call, t1a.c1, t1a.c2, t1b.c2,
  t1a.c2 - t1b.c2 as diff, t2.symbol, t2.limit,
  case t2.symbol
    when '>' then
      case when t1a.c2-t1b.c2 > t2.limit then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end
    when '<' then
      case when t1a.c2-t1b.c2 < t2.limit then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end
    when '=' then
      case when t1a.c2-t1b.c2 = t2.limit then 'PASS' else 'FAIL' end
  end as status
from table1 t1a
join table1 t1b on t1b.call = t1a.call and t1b.c1 = t1a.c1 and t1b.c2 < t1a.c2
join table2 t2 on t2.call = t1a.call
order by t1a.call, t1b.c1;

CALL C1 C2 C2       DIFF S      LIMIT STATUS
---- -- -- -- ---------- - ---------- ------
c001 a  11 10          1 >         10 FAIL  
c001 b  25 13         12 >         10 PASS
```

But there's significant repetition so if you have more than a few symbols to deal with it won't scale well, for maintainability at least.

As a more general, if a bit more obscure, approach you could bounce through a kind of dynamic evaluation via an XML type:

```
select t1a.call, t1a.c1, t1a.c2, t1b.c2,
  t1a.c2 - t1b.c2 as diff, t2.symbol, t2.limit,
  xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/*/text()'
  passing xmltype(
    dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select case when ' || (t1a.c2-t1b.c2) || t2.symbol || t2.limit
      || ' then ''PASS'' else ''FAIL'' end from dual')
  )
  returning content) as status
from table1 t1a
join table1 t1b on t1b.call = t1a.call and t1b.c1 = t1a.c1 and t1b.c2 < t1a.c2
join table2 t2 on t2.call = t1a.call
order by t1a.call, t1b.c1;

CALL C1 C2 C2       DIFF S      LIMIT STATUS
---- -- -- -- ---------- - ---------- ------
c001 a  11 10          1 >         10 FAIL  
c001 b  25 13         12 >         10 PASS
```

Or you can use dymanic SQL, building up a similar string to run and evaluate.

Either way this is painful and awkward, so you might want to look at other ways to capture the business rules.

I've also had to guess that you can decide which of the two rows to subtract from the other based on one being larger. But that also assumes they can't be equal - if they can be then the join condition won't find them at all (and if you change the join condition it'll match rows to themselves, so you'd have to check for different row IDs too).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ed5194b71139fa29c76d826d2a8c2f2)

Comment: Thanks much Alex.. The first query helped me out. :-)